# Can you explain mathematical and mechanics formulation of equation in Junker 1969 paper on self-loosening of fastener by vibration?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, friction, fasteners, threads

Can you help me to understand how the first equation in the paper 'New Criteria for Self-Loosening of Fasteners Under Vibration' by GH Junker, 1969 is derived? I'm not able to understand the mathematical and mechanics formulation as I tried to derive the same equation by myself.
Please refer to below images for reference to the equations and the text in the paper.
The ρ = e is friction angle (mentioned at the end of paper) hence, (tan ρ) = µ and
φ is angle of inclination of the plane (my guess).

[image: diagram] [image: text description]

Answer (score 0):

Junker and other later researchers
all point to the importance of preventing
transverse joint movement. A bolted
joint, properly designed so that the
clamp force from the bolts is sufficient to
prevent transverse movement by friction
grip between the joint plates, will not
come loose.

I don't understand this formula either as it is not dependent on the torque of the fastener, rather just the just the angles of static friction.